# Test function for Weak formulation

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Can anybody give an elaborate explanation as to why we multiply a test function on both sides of the boundary value problem and then integrate it into the procedure of weak formulation?
e.g A BVP
$$ -\nabla (A \nabla u) = f \quad \text{on} \quad\Omega$$
$$ u = g \quad \text{on} \quad \partial \Omega$$
For weak formulation we do,
$$\int_{\Omega} \phi (-\nabla (A \nabla u) -f) d\Omega = 0$$
Here $\phi$ is the test function

Comment: I think the b.v.p you're considering is $-\nabla \cdot (A \nabla u)=f$, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this SE post: [Finite Element Method Weak Formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754511/finite-element-method-weak-formulation)

The key point is the notion of *weak* solution. The weak solution $u$
(after some suitable assumptions on $A$ and $f$ in order to ensure coercivity and boundedness) of that problem is not $C^2$, but requires less smoothness than the so-called *strong* solution. So you're relaxing your regularity assumptions, allowing solutions that are not twice differentiable, which are pretty common in applications. This may arise even with simple 1D Poisson problems: consider $-u''(x) = f(x)$ where $f$ is discontinuous. If you do the steps, you'll realise that $u \notin C^2$ on the whole domain. This is pretty informal, and you should try to have a closer look at all of this with a good reference.

Furthermore, the weak formulation of the problem is not the one you wrote, it's slightly different: you're searching a $u \in V$ such that

$$a(u,\phi)=l(\phi)$$

for every $\phi \in V$ where $V$ is an appropriate Sobolev space. Here $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a suitable bilinear form, and $l$ a linear functional. Actually, you could be more general and choose a space for test functions which is different from the space where the weak solution $u$ lives. (keyword: Petrov-Galerkin, but this complicates things a little).

In your particular case, you'll have to consider $V=H^1_{\Gamma_D}(\Omega)$ where $\Gamma_D = \partial \Omega$ in this case since you have Dirichlet b.c. on all the boundary.

To solve your problem, you can set $\hat{u} = u-R_g(x)$, where $R_g(x)$ is the so called boundary lifting and it has "value" $g$ on the boundary and $0$ in the interior of the domain. Note that $\hat{u}$ solves the homogeneous problem, because $\hat{u}_{|\partial \Omega} = u_{|\partial \Omega} - R_g(x) = 0$ by definition of $R_g$.

Now, by Green's identity you readily have that you have to search a $\hat{u} \in V$ s.t. $$\int_{\Omega}\nabla \hat{u} \cdot \nabla \phi= \int_\Omega f \phi - \int_{\Omega} \nabla R_g\cdot \nabla \phi $$ for every $\phi \in V$. Once you obtain $\hat{u}$, the solution $u$ will be finally given by $u=\hat{u} + R_g$.

Comment: I understand. But, why do we use a test function $\phi$. What is the importance of that function?

Comment: @Rip97 In your particular case, they allow you to define the notion of weak solution. Given that, you will allow a solution to be less smooth and, as I said before, this is crucial as "physical" solutions may not be smooth and so you really need less regularity. 

You may want to have a look here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20327/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-test-function-in-finite-element-analysis?noredirect=1&lq=1.

or maybe here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304209/what-does-test-function-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1